# How did a user without the "Edit Questions And Answers" privilege review Suggested Edits?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits, reputation, privileges

User [Dany Maor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2202232/dany-maor) just [received the Custodian badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2278/custodian?userid=2202232) for reviewing a Suggested Edit.

[That privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) isn't awarded until 2000 reputation.

Comment: See also: [Reviewing “Suggested Edits” with less than 2000 points?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169336/262755)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The author of a post can always unconditionally reject or accept a suggested edit on their *own posts*, regardless of reputation.

Dany Maor [rejected a suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5909057) on [their own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26164531/read-function-as-string-from-text-file-and-use-the-function). Note that their name is highlighted with a blue background, signifying 'author of post'.

Comment: is this intentional, or was it just a side-effect nobody considered but also nobody ended up patching it?

Comment: @LonelyNeuron: this is intentional.

Answer (score 9):

I believe if a user suggested an edit on one of the answers he'd posted, then he will have been given the opportunity to approve or deny that edit.

I earned the same badge today for approving a suggested improvement to one of my answers.