# Can askers always review edits on their own question?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits, privileges

When editing questions, I encountered approvals from the asker who had not enough reputation for reviewing. What are the rules for it?

[Here I made a lot of edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6462899) that the asker (who obviously has much more difficulties with English) may find helpful. Should I point him/her on it via comment to explicitly request an approval?

Comment: Yes, original author can always review any edits on their posts. Reputation is required to review edits on other user's posts.

Comment: @Sunshine Just to be clear: only 1 rep is needed for askers?

Comment: Yes, only one rep is required for askers. Related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272684/how-did-a-user-with-69-rep-review-suggested-edits

Comment: @Sunshine: There is no rep requirement. Just the requirement of the post being your own.

Comment: @Cerbrus There is no rep less than 1, right?

Comment: Sure, you can't get less than 1 rep. But that doesn't mean 1 rep is a requirement. Rep is completely irrelevant here.

Comment: @gnat Does it make much sense to mark a question as a duplicate of a duplicate?

Comment: I suggested one that I think better describes the issue

Comment: @gnat, True, the Question text is much clearer. But there are less votes on it and its answers...

Comment: I hope that this will change as time goes by. Clearer text is easier to find and if it gets more visits (and votes), these will eventually correct things (I've seen this happening to other questions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q: *Can askers always review edits on their own question?*
A: Yes.

When someone suggests an edit to your question (Or answer), you get a notification saying so. Clicking this notification takes you to the suggested edit, so you can review it.

A post's owner has the binding vote in regards to suggested edits.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile, I found the relevant FAQ entry:

[**How do suggested edits work? - Meta Stack Exchange**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

*...which also includes special "owner" rules for answers.*

Answer (score 0):

You need 2K reputation to review edits, unless you are the original author of the content: You can always review and see edits on your own posts / questions.

### Related post:

- [How did a user without the "Edit Questions And Answers" privilege review Suggested Edits?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272684/how-did-a-user-with-69-rep-review-suggested-edits)

Comment: No, this isn't the asker, but a regular reviewer. I linked just for showing the amount of changes I made.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, I misunderstood the question. In that case yes, you only need 1 reputation to review edits on your own post, just like Sunshine said.

Comment: BTW: You know that you can (suggest to) delete your answer?

Comment: You should edit and fix your answer. Don't delete it, improve it. Never hesitate to edit and modify your answers and make them better :)

Comment: Improved answer to answer original question ;-)