# Is this an acceptable edit?

Tags: discussion, edits

I have come across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33383620/how-to-get-image-uri) and after I opened the question an [edit was approved](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33383620/2) and I feel that the edit isn't of a good quality and would like to know if this is how posts should be edited?

Also, [the person who reviewed the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5448381/waqas-shah-mashwani) has a reputation score of 6 so how was he able to approve the edit?

Comment: OP can *always* approve edits on they own post. There is no reputation restrictions as far as I know in such case.

Comment: Ah OK, makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invalid edit. Edit looks like audit - every other word is wrapped in "code" marks (which is not good practice - [Is using backticks for inline quotes acceptable?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308047/is-using-backticks-for-inline-quotes-acceptable/308050#308050)).

This edit would likely be rejected if it had gone through review queue, but it was approved by OP. Note that OP have binding vote on edits to their own posts irrespective of reputation ([How did a user without the "Edit Questions And Answers" privilege review Suggested Edits?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272684/how-did-a-user-without-the-edit-questions-and-answers-privilege-review-suggest))

Answer (score 1):

Edits meant to make the post better in one or more ways.

One of the reasons to edit is fixing grammatical errors. If the main text is hard to understand because of the language usage issues, then you try to fix it to make it more easier to understand.

Another reason is fixing the title or the tags to help the post reach more people. Good titling and tagging is important.

You may edit a post to add a an important notice too, like adding some information about a bug/threat that may be occur because of the related situation.

Last reason is increasing readability. You fix code block to make the code readable, or fix the improper usage of formatting tools.

---

Now, related edit is done none of those, it do not fix the grammar, it do not improve the title or the tags or anything else. So we can say it was an invalid edit. But beyond that, using a text format tool like that decreases the readability. Here is not a forum or similar place where people tries to highlight their reply to get attention. And **usage** *of* ***too*** `much text` **styling** *is* ***`indeed bad`***. Probably nobody felt comfortable while reading previous sentence.

For me, minor edits should be rejected. But if they are approved somehow, then it is okay too. But that edit is something that should be fixed or roll-backed (like it is already done) since it decreases the readability nd makes the post worse.